# Why not solve for the normal equation formula using matrix algebra instead of calculus?

Tags: regression, self-study

When dealing with regression, specifically the normal equation, it is derived via calculus, as it is here:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/derivation-of-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression

But, I don't see where you even need calculus. Why not just do the following using basic matrix operations (assuming that $X^T  X$ is invertible):
$$
X\beta = y \\
X^T \cdot X\beta = X^T\cdot y \\
(X^T  X)^{-1}\cdot X^T  X\beta = (X^T  X)^{-1}\cdot X^T y \\
\beta = (X^T  X)^{-1}\cdot X^Ty \\
$$

Is there anything wrong with this?

One problem I have with this is: doesn't this imply that the resulting $\beta $ will make it so that the plane actually interpolates every point of $y$. This is often not the case when doing linear regression, so this is what seems weird.

Comment: Yes, the first assumption, that $X\beta = y$, is wrong. In Linear regression, the assumption is $y = X\beta + \epsilon$

Comment: @TimMak Hmmm, what about if you collect data and are only looking at the realizations (ie data). Then you would have a vector $y$ and a matrix $X$ and the $\epsilon$ are not really present. Then your objective is to solve for the vector $\beta$ .

Comment: $\epsilon$ are present. You don't have $X\beta=y$, you have $X\beta+\epsilon=y$, as Tim said. So your method for solving isn't applicable here since it's based off an equation that isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks everyone, after researching some more I finally stumbled upon what was causing the confusion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577065/using-the-left-inverse-to-solve-an-impossible-system-of-equations

Comment: Then, if you solved your problem, you can answer your own question here (in the answer box) so it does not linger on as unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that was messing me up was something from linear algebra, or just regular algebra really.

---

The statement $$a=b \quad\Longrightarrow\quad Ta=Tb$$ is true, but the converse $$Ta=Tb \quad\Longrightarrow\quad a=b$$ is not always true.