# Why use least squared solution of linear regression when we can use X inverse?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I know linear regression gets the estimate of beta by minimizing the squared errors. I'm curious why can't I use inverse of X to get the estimate of beta. I know there is errors and etc. but if X inverse exists, can we just estimate the beta using X ^(-1)?

X * beta = Y

beta = X^(-1) * Y

This does not sound right, but I'm not sure how to disprove it either.

Comment: For one thing, the inverse of $X$ will not exist, if it is not a square matrix

Comment: This keeps getting asked... but searching for the dups is next to impossible.  This one is close: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466364.  For the record, [here is the search I used to find the duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=regression%20X%20inver*%20solve).

Comment: @RobertLong maybe a dumb question, but do you know why only square matrix has an inverse?

Comment: Well X * beta does not equal Y but our predictions y_hat. So Y = X * beta + e (some error vector). So to minimize the error we say e = Y - X * beta and square both sides.  When solving and minimizing for that we then get the typical OLS equation.

Comment: @datalover inversion is only defined for square matrices.